# Copying values between Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange, google-sheets-filter

I have 2 Google Sheets. I have data on Google Sheet A and I would like it to automatically transfer some values to Google Sheet b.

For example, I have some email addresses and some data associated with them organized by row. So one row corresponds to one email address. I want to be able to take the existing data (and any data I add) on sheet A and and have it automatically transfer certain values in sheet A to sheet B (matched by columns) such that if I input the email address on sheet B on an email address column in sheet B it will auto-populate values from cells corresponding to that email addresses row in sheet A. So once I insert the email address in sheet B it will take the corresponding name of that person in sheet A and input it in the name column I have in sheet B.

What type of function would I need to write for this?

Comment: depends of your spreadsheets and how they look like. it can be `IMPORTRANGE`, `FILTER`, `QUERY`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be solved in many ways, one of which is:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL-of-your-spreadsheet"; "Sheet1!A:Z")
```